# Is there any way that can display all the permission info of folders/files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way that can display all the permission info in Google Drive? I have maybe hundred folders and files for years and I want to change the permission for some people. I know how to change permission from the folder, but it's impossible to check them one by one, is there any way or maybe an app to do this faster and easier?

Comment: I suspect that most people have tens of thousands of files, not merely "hundreds".